# Codeigniter setting upload path out of installation folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have problem uploading the files, whenever i echo

```
$this->upload->display_errors();
```

this gives error `The upload path does not appear to be valid.`

my directory structure

```
- main
   - CI_Installation
   - uploads
     - brochures
```

The test i m doing is in my local machine. In production server the two inside folders will be in root folder instead of `main` folder.

I want to upload files to the `uploads` folder, i.e. outside CI installation folder. I have tried setting path
`./uploads/brochures/`
`../../uploads/brochures/` and every other possible path but still getting that error.

**Edit**

I know i have something wrong in path, folder permission would have yield another error. The error explicitly says `The upload path does not appear to be valid.`

Below is snippet of the code, posting whole controller is not feasible because it has several lines of code, which might be difficult to read.

```
                    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/brochures/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|docx|doc';
                $config['max_size'] = '10000';
                $config["remove_spaces"]=TRUE;
                $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
                $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload("b_path");
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                echo "ERRORS = ".$this->upload->display_errors();
```

Can anybody help me here?

Thanks

Comment: I know that could be stupid but... how about the folder write permissions?

Comment: @manix, i m on windows in my local machine so folder permission would not be the issue here.

Comment: @JordanArseno, question updated, please see it

Comment: does the `brochures` directory exist? I ask because you said "my directory structure is"... but then didn't include it.

Comment: @JordanArseno, brochures directory is inside `uploads` directory and it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself. I set the constant `UPLOAD_PATH` in `constants.php`

```
define('UPLOAD_PATH',dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads/');
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are on the localhost then you should change upload path to this

```
c:\wamp\www\ci_installation\upload\
```

And on the server if you set the path as you have done it will work ok.
if have given you the path of your wamp installation if you are using something else then  give the path according to your installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FCPATH constant then use '../' to go one directory up until you reach the desired folder.